# How to reduce class list in Bulma

Tags: css, grid, bulma

How can I reduce the class definition for Bulma column which actually looks like this

```
<div class="column is-three-quarters-mobile is-three-quarters-tablet is-three-quarters-desctop is-three-quarters-widescreen is-three-quarters-fullhd"></div>
```

This is really bad. Hope there is a way to only one class to do what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want your column to have a 3/4 size no matter the size of the viewport.
You can just use the `is-three-quarters` class which is gonna work for all sizes except **mobile**.

To make it work on mobile too you have to add the `is-mobile` class to your columns containers [as explained in the documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/#mobile-columns), so your code looks like this:

```
<div class="columns is-mobile">
    <div class="column is-three-quarters"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is it. Thank you.